# C# swagger documentation for individual members of the request body object

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle

We are writing swagger documentation using /// comments in the following way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a new widget
/// </summary>
/// <param name="widget"></param>
[HttpPost("/create")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IPayment), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResult), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResult), 404)]
public Task<IActionResult> CreateWidget([FromBody] Widget widget)
{
```

Now Widget is an implementation of IWidget and the user of the documentation should know in detail what each data member of Widget / IWidget means, what's mandatory, what's optional, and valid values.

We found that the only place to add this description is in

```
/// <param name="widget">very big multi line description</param>
```

While this works for the end user, is there a better way? We ask this because it is much more maintainable if the descriptions are provided inline in the class / interface definition.

Answer (score 4):

On the same way you document your actions with the `///` comments you can also document your models

Here is an example:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Location#/Location/Location_Get2

The code for that looks like:

```
/// <summary>
/// ## Geographic coordinates
/// ___
/// A **geographic coordinate system** is a coordinate system used in geography that enables every location on Earth
/// </summary>
public class Location
{
    /// <summary>**Latitude**: a geographic coordinate that specifies the north–south position of a point on the Earth's surface.</summary>
    /// <example>25.85</example>
    [Range(-90, 90)]
    public float Lat { get; set; }

    /// <summary>**Longitude**: a geographic coordinate that specifies the east-west position of a point on the Earth's surface.</summary>
    /// <example>-80.27</example>
    [Range(-180, 180)]
    public float Lon { get; set; }
}
```

---

This is how it looks like:
[image]

---

On Post or Put requests the documentation can also be seen on the model tab:

https://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Company
[image]

And as usual under the Models:
[image]

Comment: That works when the model is tagged `[FromRoute]` or `[FromQuery]`, but it doesn't work for models bound `[FromBody]` which is what the OP was asking

Comment: Are you sure about that @Ian ? as far as I can see the documentation is there in the models section, the tag does not matter ... I will add a couple of image to this answer from that same link I posted

Comment: My apologies @Helder, you're correct.  I was confused since the link shows route parameters and I was expecting to see body parameters in the same place.  I wasn't checking the Model (or on my page "Schema") view.  I still feel it is too hidden though.  It would be nice if Swashbuckle allowed us to document body parameters the same way that route parameters are done.

Comment: Additionally my body parameters are arrays, which was complicating things.  They don't show any of the summary/remarks/example text in the example body, which contributed to my misunderstanding.  Even the schema view only shows Summary.  Remarks/Example are ignored for arrays (of in-built types).

Comment: @Ian there is a clear separation between Swashbuckle and SwaggerUI that you might not know ... Swashbuckle just generates the OpenApi/swagger compliant doc: https://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1 ... SwaggerUI "eats" that doc and spits the wonderful UI we see, if you want something improved there request it here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: Agreed.  I lazily threw in the term "Swashbuckle" because I don't know whether it's Swashbuckle, OpenApi, or SwaggerUI that prevents documenting body parameters, and I have no inclination to spend the hours required to learn who the culprit is.  There is probably a very good reason why it is so.  It just works against me in this case.